# How to compile Python extension with debug info using PIP

Tags: python-c-extension

I have source code for an extension in Python. I want to see debug symbols for that extension when I debug it. How do I tell PIP to compile and link debug symbols for my extension?

(Preferably platform agnostic, else Linux)

Answer (score 14):

You need to invoke `setup.py`'s `build` command with `--debug` flag during package installation. Using `pip` additional flags to `setup.py` can be passed using `--global-option`:

```
pip install --no-binary :all: --global-option build --global-option --debug PACKAGE
```

In case of errors try upgrading `pip` and `setuptools`:

```
pip install -U setuptools
pip install -U pip
```

I found this information in this blogpost by Jonathan Lange: https://jml.io/2015/08/debugging-python-with-gdb.html