Why "PyRun_SimpleString("from PIL import Image")" does not work in debug mode?
I'm writing a c++ program that use Python library EasyOCR to read some text. I wrote such code:
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("import easyocr");
//Other codes

When I run it in Release mode, it works fine, but if I switch to Debug mode, it reports a run-time error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\easyocr\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .easyocr import Reader
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\easyocr\easyocr.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .recognition import get_recognizer, get_text
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\easyocr\recognition.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 100, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py)

Then I tried to run
PyRun_SimpleString("from PIL import Image");

insteaed of
PyRun_SimpleString("import easyocr");

but the same error was reported again:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 100, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py)

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11 x64 to write my c++ code.My Python version is
Python 3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr  4 2023, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

My Pillow version is 10.4.0 and easyocr version is 1.7.2
I have already downloaded the debug symbols via python installer, and set the project's debug config to use the python311_d.lib.
I want to know why it is reporting such error and what should I do to debug this program in Visual Studio.
Update:
I use the debug version of python (python_d.exe) to run the import syntax, it reports the same error.
PS C:\Users\15819> python_d
Python 3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr  4 2023, 23:34:25) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyreadline3\lineeditor\history.py:87: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\15819\\.python_history' mode='r' encoding='utf-8'>
  for line in open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8'):
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
>>> import sys
>>> import easyocr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\easyocr\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .easyocr import Reader
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\easyocr\easyocr.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .recognition import get_recognizer, get_text
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\easyocr\recognition.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 100, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py)
>>> from PIL import Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 100, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py)


_imaging is probably an extension module built for release. You need to build it for debug interpreter (python_d.exe).

I tried to run it in python_d.exe, then I saw the same error. How can I rebuild this? @Osyort

Binary Python modules are just DLLs. If one of them lacks a dependency (i.e. another DLL that can't be loaded), loading that DLL fails, too. You can use regular dev tools to examine your setup. Generally, there is also the option to use the release runtime but still create debug symbols for stepping through the code. Those are usually bundled, but not enforced.

Probably this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37888453
